Why does ZarrArraySource get an unexpected argument when loading data with intake in VSCode?
I am using data from an Earth Model System called nextGEMS, but when I try to load it in VSCode I get the following message:
TypeError: ZarrArraySource.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'consolidated'

Here is the code I have used:
import intake
import xarray as xr
import zarr

cat = intake.open_catalog("https://data.nextgems-h2020.eu/catalog.yaml")
data = cat.IFS['IFS_4.4-FESOM_5-cycle3']
data2 = data['2D_1h_native'].to_dask()


And then I get the following: Error message
If I run the same code in JupyterNotebook everything works well.

That is super weird! Perhaps VSCode provides you with a way to debug exactly what is getting called and the environment?

Hey @mdurant and thanks for your reply. Would you mind telling me how can I debug what is getting called? I am a newbie in VSCode

I have no idea!
